# Банальный вопрос. Минуту вашего времени. Метод GET для получения данных, а метод POST для отправки данных? JS, Request

Tags: javascript, post, get, request

В гугле я нашел что, post это для данных только "секретных", а get для "публичных". Я смотрю туториал. Автор говорит, что если хочется получить данные, надо метод get, а если отправить то метод post. Просто хочется удостовериться, он прав? Вот часть кода:

```
async createPost(post) {
    try {
        const request = new Request(this.url + "/posts.json", {
            method: "post", // отправка данных?
            body: JSON.stringify(post)

        });
        const response = await fetch(request);
        return await response.json
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

}




async fetchPosts() {
    try {
        const request = new Request(`${this.url}/posts.json`,
            {
                method: "get" // получение данных?
            });
        const response = await fetch(request);
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Весь код: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnet1kxq/

Я просто хочу узнать, get только для получения данных, а post для отправки данных?

Comment: нет не совсем так

Comment: можно чуть подробнее? Я в гугле не нашел о том, что get для получения данных, а post для отправки данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если погуглить то можно найти полно примеров
вот что [пишут](https://habr.com/ru/post/215117/)

Основная идея запросов. - Вы отправляете запрос методом (post, get, ...) прикрепляя данные каким-то образом (в заголовке, в пути, в теле), в ответ вам высылаются данные.
Основные различия в формировании самого запроса, у кого есть тело у кого нет. И ответ у кого полный у кого нет. А менять данные можно любым способом. Поймите это запрос, а что делать с ним решать вам. У каждого типа запроса есть небольшая [философия](https://habr.com/ru/post/50147/) например у get - то что его можно кешировать.